# из MySQL в JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Имею много таблиц в БД с разных кол-вом полей, которые необходимо вывести в `JTable`. Идея такова:

```
 private void createUIComponents() {
    Connection connection;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,login,password);
        String select = "SELECT * FROM printinghousedb.districts";
        Vector<String> fields = new Vector();
        fields.add("DistrictId");
        fields.add("DistrictName");
        DistrictsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        Vector data = new Vector();
        data = getTable(connection,select,fields);
        DistrictsTable = new JTable(data, fields);
        //инициализация других таблиц...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Vector[] getTable(Connection  connection, String request, Vector fields) throws 
SQLException {
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(request);
  while (rs.next()) {
//...
```

Не знаю что делать дальше, как из `ResultSet` формировать `Vector`?

**Обновление**

`DistrictsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);` — лишняя строка, оставшаяся от предыдущих попыток. Забыл убрать, извиняюсь.

Comment: а зачем вы 2 раза создаете таблицу? более правильным вариантом будет реализация собственного класса наследника TableModel. более простым будет использования конструктора с параметром `Object[][]`

Answer (score 0):

`Vector` содежит метод `add()`. Используйте его:

```
Vector<Vector<>> mainVector = new Vector<Vector<>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector vec = new Vector<>();
    vec.add(rs.getString(1));
    vec.add(rs.getString(2));
    vec.add(rs.getString(3));
    // и так далее
    mainVector.add(vec);
}
```

И еще немного непонятна эта часть:

```
//data не инициализирована, имели ввиду fields?
DistrictsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames); 
Vector data = new Vector();
data = getTable(connection,select,fields);
DistrictsTable = new JTable(data, fields);
```

Comment: там не просто `Vector`, а `Vector` из  `Vector`.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman исправил